# Does Google Natural Language API use BERT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-nl

A week ago, Google announced (https://blog.google/products/search/search-language-understanding-bert), that they will use BERT (https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/11/open-sourcing-bert-state-of-art-pre.html) for better understanding search queries and for featured snippets.

My question is therefore, if BERT is also used in the Natural Language API or are these two separate systems?

Answer (score 0):

BERT is both a model that can be trained and a pre-tained layer that you can use as a first understanding of the input text before the training of your layer takes place.

In that sense, Google allows you to do this second thing in GCP Machine learning taking advantage of TPU's. You can see how [here.](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert)

As for if Google uses BERT in his NLP API, I have not been able to find that such is the case, although it could be that they use it under the hood.